# How to see VSCode popups for sessions in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, visual-studio-code

I'm making something with SQLAlchemy, and I have a trivial but annoying problem.
I make a session like this:

```
engine=create_engine(db,echo=True)
Session= sessionmaker(bind=engine)
s=Session()
```

The issue is that VSCode doesnt show me any function list or documentation popup when I use `s`. I want to be able to see the documentation popups for this at least. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If it was `s=Session` it will prompt some alternative list, because it can infer the type of `s`:

[image]

while `s=Session()` will not:

[image]